# Return a empty string if return is empty

Tags: php

So I have the following method that is sending back a response to my API, but I have one small problem that I'm trying to overcome.

```
public function transform($employee)
    {
        return [
            'birthday' => $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d'),
            'hire_date' => $employee['hire_date']->format('Y-m-d'),
        ];
    }
```

The `'birthday' and 'hire_date'` return values back, but is there a way that I can define an empty string if there is no value?

Something along the lines like this: `'birthday' => $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') :? '',`

Comment: you could use null-coalese depending on the output of your format function. `$foo = $bar ?? '';` will set $foo to '' if $bar is null.

Comment: Why not check for the values?

Comment: Hi @Gavin, this is me Tripp - This didn't work for me for some reason, since the values in the DB are stored as `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```php
public function transform($employee)
    {
        return [
            'birthday' => !empty($employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d')) ? $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') : "",
            'hire_date' => !empty($employee['hire_date']->format('Y-m-d')) ? $employee['hire_date']->format('Y-m-d') : "",
        ];
    }
```

Additionally, if you're running php 7 or greater, you can use the `null coalescing operator` like this:

```php
public function transform($employee)
    {
        return [
            'birthday' => $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') ?? ""
            'hire_date' => $employee['hire_date']->format('Y-m-d') ?? "",
        ];
    }
```

You can find more info in the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

PS. as pointed out in the comments, the date `format` function will always return something, or a warning if `$employee['birthday']` is null. So better to place the check on `$employee['birthday']` like so:

```php
            'birthday' => !empty($employee['birthday']) ?
                $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') "",
```

Comment: But when will the expression ever evaluate to false? If there are DateTime objects stored in the array, any result of ```format``` will be truthy, will it not? If on the other hand ```$employee['birthday']``` is null, ```format``` will result in an error, and that will not be caught by the ternary or null-coalescing operator

Comment: You make a good point. I'll include this as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Hi @gaganshera, this is me Tripp - This didn't work for me for some reason, since the values in the DB are stored as `0000-00-00`.

Comment: Ahh, in that case you'd have to compare the date to 'birthday' => $employee['birthday'] !== '0000-00-00' ? $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') : ""`

Comment: Although, I'd advise you to clean your data. An "empty" date shouldn't be stored as `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 0):

As the values are stored as `'0000-00-00'` when NO value is present (which is obviously not empty), we can try `strcmp()` to solve this.

```
public function transform($employee){
    return [
        'birthday' => strcmp($employee['birthday'],"0000-00-00") !=0 ? $employee['birthday']->format('Y-m-d') : "",
        'hire_date' => strcmp($employee['hire_date'], "0000-00-00") != 0? $employee['hire_date']->format('Y-m-d') : ""
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi @San, this is me Tripp - This didn't work for me for some reason, since the values in the DB are stored as `0000-00-00`.

Comment: So you are aying that, when NO value is present in a particular field, it is stored as *'0000-00-00'*, right ?

Comment: Correct @San, it's stored as '0000-00-00' when there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just easier to split things up in easy to read short commands.

```
public function transform($employee)
    {
        $birthday   = $employee['birthday'];
        $hire_date  = $employee['hire_date'];

        $birthday  = (!empty($birthday)) ? $birthday->format('Y-m-d') : '';
        $hire_date = (!empty($hire_date)) ? $hire_date->format('Y-m-d') : '';

        return [            
            'birthday'  => $birthday,
            'hire_date' => $hire_date,
        ];
    }
```

If you wanted code without repetition you could do something like:

```
public function transform($employee)
    {
        $dates = [$employee['birthday'], $employee['hire_date']];

        foreach ($dates as $index => $date) {       
             $dates[$index] = !empty($date) ? $date->format('Y-m-d') : '';
        }

        return $dates;  

    }
```

In case you wanted to increase the number of dates to work on, all you need to do is add that date to the dates array. No further changes required.

Comment: Hi @RST, it's me Tripp - I just tried this and it doesn't seem to be working for me because the values in the DB are stored as `0000-00-00`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. All you need to do is change !empty() to != '0000-00-00'. That is a small adjustment to make. The principle still works.

Comment: I tried using it as the following `(!= '0000-00-00') ? $birthday->format('Y-m-d') : '',` and `($birthday != '0000-00-00') ? $birthday->format('Y-m-d') : '',` but I'm getting errors.

Comment: yes coz that is not a correct command. You didn't write the code you are sharing with us, right? Otherwise you would have known how to edit it. $date != '0000-00-00'